# Extreme estimated coefficients

Tags: r, estimation, linear-model, intercept

Below is a part of my `summary(lmfit)`. It shows a very extreme intercept.

I can successfully calculate some fitted values based on the coefficients. 
However as soon as I attempt this for one of the less extreme values I end up with very strange values because I need extreme values to "nullify" the extreme intercept.

Is it normal to have such extreme estimated values / is there a (simple) fix for this?

The model is calculated using the `fastLm` function from the `RcppArmadillo` package.

```
formula <- DRIP_WEIGHT ~ LGP_CODE + SEX_CODE + PROTOCOL_TTQ + HCW_SCALED +AGE_TTQ +  HYS_TTQ

Call:
fastLm.formula(formula = formula, data = res)

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-28.40200  -2.13390  -0.27502   1.77610 132.45000 

                                      Estimate                  StdErr              t.value               p.value    
(Intercept)              1387901450219.1755371               0.8769739   1582602923393.9170 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
LGP_CODELGPDSAA                      0.4302362               0.1906645               2.2565              0.024045 *  
LGP_CODELGPDASS           -87888266462.0417175               0.4677715   -187887185415.1603 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
LGP_CODELGPDAAS                      0.0335304               0.1980017               0.1693              0.865527    
LGP_CODELGPDSSA           -87888266462.2230530               0.4664520   -188418653123.9235 < 0.00000000000000022 ***

SEX_CODEX                            0.6330295               0.1011811               6.2564       0.0000000003984 ***
SEX_CODEZ                            0.6077352               0.0608334               9.9902 < 0.00000000000000022 ***

PROTOCOL_TTQYDICTOR       369192250204.6542969               0.5707083    646901891377.9446 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
PROTOCOL_TTQTN_NIRS                  0.7747033               0.7113210               1.0891              0.276115    
HCW_SCALED                           0.0267529               0.0029718               9.0022 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
AGE_MQY                             -0.0030477               0.0024025              -1.2686              0.204599    

HYS_TTQ200202146897                -11.7255468               0.9285184             -12.6282 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
HYS_TTQ200203146897                -11.7690543               0.8991546             -13.0890 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
HYS_TTQ200204146897                -12.6353209               0.8990323             -14.0544 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
HYS_TTQ200204735728     -1387901450214.1433105               0.6107452  -2272472295975.4731 < 0.00000000000000022 ***

OBSERVATION2                        -0.4382104               0.0411196             -10.6570 < 0.00000000000000022 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.442 on 36010 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4464, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4381
```

Here's an overview of the data used in the model:

```
'data.frame':   36552 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ PIG_ID      : int  7180460 7348216 7719385 8078074 8411212 8943509 9041233 9041254 9083773 9280891 ...
     $ DRIP_WEIGHT : num  17 4 8 5 6 4 10 4 3 10 ...
 $ LGP_CODE    : Factor w/ 15 levels "LGPBRFNG","LGPDDCB",..: 14 14 14 14 14 14 9 9 9 13 ...
     $ SEX_CODE    : Factor w/ 3 levels "B","X","Z": 3 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ PROTOCOL_TTQ: Factor w/ 8 levels "AUT_BCN_PB","CAN_BCN_PB",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ HCW_SCALED  : num  -5.7 0 8.3 -4.9 -8.2 -0.7 -8.7 -9.7 1.3 2.3 ...
 $ AGE_TTQ     : num  188 194 202 185 188 209 199 196 177 180 ...
     $ HYS_TTQ     : Factor w/ 516 levels "200010146897",..: 1 2 5 9 12 16 15 15 17 21 ...
 $ OBSERVATION : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ VALID_COLUMN: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: No, this is not normal. I would first check my input data. Your data could actually contain some extreme values and those are probably not plausible. However, much more information would be needed to diagnose the problem. You don't even give the model formula.

Comment: @Roland Added the formula and some extra information about the dataset! (I didn't remove it on purpose). Hope it's enough now:)

Comment: @Roland Could it be because of data not being grouped correctly into factors(e.g. too small groups)?

Comment: I think this is just a misspecified model. Your formula clearly shows that you don't really know what you are doing there. `(HCW_SCALED*HCW_SCALED)` is not a quadratic term. It's an interaction of an effect with itself, which apparently is dropped by `fastLm`. You should look some more into your data (e.g., create cross-tables and appropriate graphs), before you attempt such a complex model, which may be too complex for what you want to achieve (you don't say).

Comment: @Roland the model has been created by other people, I'm just trying to re-implement it into a new project. Thanks for this extra insight tho, I'll adjust my formula. I've also talked about this problem with my supervisor, the extreme values happen because of interaction. For example, LGP_CODELGPDSSA only happens in combination with another factor, together they yield normal output.

Comment: If `LGP_CODELGPDSSA` only happens together with another factor, you should recode it accordingly. Parameter estimates that differ by many orders of magnitude can result in numeric problems.

Comment: @Roland So in this case, I would have to merge those two factors that can only happen together. And in what kind of problems could the parameter estimates that differ by many orders of magnitude result?